# My device doesn't react to touches while connected via USB

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, samsung-galaxy-ace, samsung, touchscreen

My device is Samsung Galaxy ace 5830 and I want to upgrade it from Android 2.3.4 to 4.
But the problem, when I connect it to PC with a USB connection, it doesn't react to touches so I can't unlock it and work with it. for example when I touch somewhere some other place get touched.

How can I upgrade it while it has this problem and I can't connect to it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:You could try to use a different USB cable, as this will sometimes interfere with the hardware.

2:Try connecting on a different USB post; the individual port could be malfunctioning

3: Have your phone already unlocked and turn off the screen sleep:

Go to > Settings | then either   > Display settings > Sleep > Never turn off screen

> General Settings > Sleep > Never turn off screen

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mentioned can be caused by the following:

1. Your micro USB port in the phone has some moisture.
2. Your micro USB port connection is loose.

If it happens normally which is not your case, it can be caused if there is moisture on your screen or droplets of water.

Try testing if this happens while using the mobile with charger connected. If it does, it is definitely the micro USB issue.

Comment: Option 3 is missing: Slightly incompatible charger/cable. The exact same behaviour I encounter when/while charging my *Motorola Milestone 2* using a HTC charger. So trying a different charger/cable might be helpful.